# Can't save my struct in a file with ofstream in c++

Tags: c++, file, save, readfile, ofstream

I am new to C++ and learn it by a book.

In my exercise, I have to save my `Pizza` struct to a file. My problem is, that `ofstream` doesn't save the price of my `Pizza`. It saves something, but I don't know what because I can't even read the saved data in the file.

Here is my header with my function:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ostream>

struct Pizza { char name[32]; float preis; };

bool createKarte();

//bool extendKart();

//void showKart();
```

And my CPP file:

```cpp
#include "Pizza_Karte.h"

const int MAXANZ = 10;

bool createKarte() {

    Pizza pizzaKarte[MAXANZ] = {
    { "Margerita", 9.90F }, { "Regina", 15.90F },
    { "Pizza Fungi", 12.50F }, { "Calzone", 14.90F } };

    //std::cout << sizeof(Pizza) << std::endl;
    std::ofstream karte("../Debug/Menue.dat", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    std::cout << pizzaKarte[0].name << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        karte.write((char*)&pizzaKarte[i], sizeof(Pizza));
    }

    std::ifstream readKarte("../Debug/Menue.dat");

    char gericht[sizeof(Pizza)];
    while (readKarte.getline(gericht, sizeof(Pizza))) {
        std::cout << gericht;
    }
```

The file `"Menue.dat"` which should contain my pizza menue:

[image]

I tried to save only the price of my menue, but I got only random characters. I have no idea why I get random characters, and can't read from my file.

Comment: I don't see where you write the price of the pizza to file.

Comment: @Mansoor `karte.write((char*)&pizzaKarte[i], sizeof(Pizza));` the output of the name is just to `std::cout`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number what does it mean to cast a float to a char*?

Comment: @Mansoor there are speical rules for casting to `char*`. Anything can be interpreted as an array of bytes.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I see, but it does explain why OP doesn't get what he expects in the file but instead sees "random characters".

Comment: The problem is that you can't view a binary file in a text editor. It's not a text file. Also in your program you are writing it as a binary file and trying to read it as a text file. The reading as text won't work for the same reason you can't read it in a text editor. It's not text.

Comment: OP: why don't you create a function `writePizza` that writes the name and then the price? Then call that function from your loop?

Comment: I just want to create a struct at the beginning and save it. Than I want to extend this menue with other functions and update my file. That is the idea.

So how I have to save this file correctly and why I cant read from them? Do I have give my getline function an mode to read binary data ?

Comment: @Reazelruss But you realize that you are saving a snapshot of what a `Pizza` looks like in memory? It's not a text file and can not be read into the program as a text file. If you use `write` you should use `read` to read the `Pizza`s in the file.

Comment: @Reazelruss -- *Than I want to extend this menue with other functions* -- Please note that this entire method of writing to binary files falls apart if `Pizza` will later contain members that are not trivially-copyable.

Comment: Also, I see so many beginners wanting to write binary files in C++, and I can't figure out the reason why.   StackOverflow is littered with hundreds of questions with ill-fated "binary file reading / writing" attempts, all due to the types being read/written not being trivially copyable, or the types contain pointers.  Writing to binary files should be reserved for persons who know *exactly* what they're doing, know the final layout of the file, and have a proper sense of serialization of the data, both input and output.

Comment: You may want to try closing (or flushing) the output file before trying to read from an input file. `karte.close();`